# Default value for String in PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, default

I'm trying to make an table, with few properties in it. My model is Account has description property, which, by default is supposed to be **"No description available for this account"**

```
CREATE TABLE accounts
(
...
description VARCHAR DEFAULT 'No description available for this account',
...
);
```

In an controller description is only set if it's not empty and not equals to "\n" like that

```
if(!description.isEmpty() && !description.equals("\n"))
{
  account.setDescription(description);
}
```

After the app runs I get a table of accounts, but the property description still equals null, with no default value. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you make an alter query on your database as: `ALTER TABLE ONLY users ALTER COLUMN lang SET DEFAULT 'en_GB';` something similar. Instead of specifying it in the program.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't solve my problem. The property description is still null

Comment: Your application is probably inserting a `null` value explicitly rather then _not_ supplying that column at all during the insert. [edit] your question and show us the code that runs the actual `insert` statement